# Setting up sendmail to perform mail routing

Tags: email, sendmail, microsoft-office-365

Is sendmail is able to do the following:
Forward many user emails to office 365:-

```
user1@example.com -> user1@internal.example.com
user2@example.com -> user2@internal.example.com
user3@example.com -> user3@internal.example.com
userx@example.com -> userx@internal.example.com
```

Forward the following to a separate server to run php scripts:-

```
sales@example.com
enquiries@example.com
```

An autoresponder will be sent to the sender.

Does anyone know of any sample configuration I could get this started on? 
Is there a good autoresponder for sendmail?

Our emails are hosted on Office365 and it does not allow us to run scripts. Therefore I was considering this option. Is this viable?

Please refer to the diagram for more information. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: It seems that even getting consultants to do this would cause around $50k ....omg..

Answer (score 0):

All unix MTAs I've ever worked with will allow you to do what you describe. I wouldn't recommend Sendmail for someone who is new to setting up email servers, though, as its configuration scripts aren't terribly easy to understand. I'd recommend [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) instead - but which MTA you choose is largely a matter of taste and what prior knowledge you may have on any given one.

A standard autoresponder in the unix world is called "vacation"; it will do the basic job of sending a reply and not causing a mail loop.

Comment: Do you have any sample configuration I can deal with the above? I understand we need to use mailertables to achieve this. However, I am not exactly clear if it would do what I need.

Comment: Have a look at the HowTos at the postfix site I linked to.

Comment: Do you know of any autoresponder that comes with postfix?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FEATURE(ldap_routing)`](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/ldap_routing.html) to route recipient to another host with or without recipient address rewrite.

It is possible to use ldap_routing **without** LDAP.

```
FEATURE(`ldap_routing', `hash:/etc/mail/mail-host', `hash:mail-address', ...)
```